# socket.io Heroku ERR_CONNECTION REFUSED

Tags: php, node.js, heroku, socket.io

Hi I'm running a php app on my heroku web dyno, and a separate node.js socket.IO app on an adjacent Worker dyno.

Now when I build to the git repo and scale the dynos up, there is only confirmation that the PHP apache server is working (since the webpage is displayed). but the socket.IO connection displays ERR_Connection_refused on chrome.

Fiddling with the port numbers leads to a worse 404 message on the socket.io connection.

Any suggestions?

**-*-*-*-EDIT-*-*-*-**
So I've replaced the worker dyno with a node dyno in the procfile and I'm still facing the same issue of ERR_connection_refused on chrome

**-*-*-*-EDIT2-*-*-*-**
I've managed to use honcho to initialize a web dyno that then spawns 2 child processes - apache and node. The apache works but the node still refuses connection.

Comment: so it turns out only web dynos can receive incoming connections.